# python flask can't display input

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm new to python and I need help with inputting value and display the value. The code shows no error and can run but the input won't display. I spent the whole yesterday working on this already.

my html code

```
<body>
<center id="form">
<form methods="POST" class="getAll">
<input type="text" id="input" onclick=""></input>
<button>Display</button>
<br>
<p id="result"><p>
</form>
</center>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>

</body>
```

my python flask code (i think something in display function not working since I can print something in-home function)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request


app = Flask(__name__)    

@app.route('/')   
def home():
    return render_template ('index.html')

@app.route('/hello_world/', methods=['POST'])
def display():
    print("hello?")
    number = int(request.form.get('inputData', 0))
    value = number
    data = {'value': value}
    data = jsonify(data)
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':  

    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

my javascript code

```
const X = document.getElementById("input").value;

$('.getAll').on('submit', function(e){
    var inpuData = $('#input').val();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello_world/',
        data: {'inputData': inputData},
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#input').val('');
            $('#result').html(data['value'])
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Add `console.log(X)` inside the `.on('submit')` and check whether it displays the value you just input in console.

Comment: @CodeIt hmm nothing show up in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
var inpuData = $('#input').val(); // see the name of the variable it is `inpu data`
```

to:

```
var inputData = $('#input').val();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank so much, i don't need to get fired after this.